# AWS cli List unused elb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-cli

I am pretty much new to AWS. I was trying to list the load balances which are not attached to any of the instances. I was trying describe-load-balancers using aws cli but was not able to get an option that filters the elbs.

Please provide some suggestions on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you have aws cli setup with suitable keys, this long line of shell should list the ELBs with a count of instances attached to them.  If it says zero then there are no instances attached

```
for i in `aws elb describe-load-balancers|sed -ne 's/"LoadBalancerName": "\(.*\)",/\1/gp'`; do echo -n "$i "; aws elb describe-load-balancers --load-balancer-name $i|grep -c InstanceId;done
```

Alternatively, here's a boto3 python program

```
import boto3
client=boto3.client('elb')
bals=client.describe_load_balancers()
for elb in bals['LoadBalancerDescriptions']:
  count=len(elb['Instances'])
  print "%s %d" % ( elb['LoadBalancerName'], count)
```

Comment: Here's a version using the ``--query`` option on AWSCLI.  It displays the load balancer name and the list of instances.  ``aws elb describe-load-balancers --query "LoadBalancerDescriptions[].[Instances,LoadBalancerName]"``

Answer (score 7):

I saw the answers above and wanted to craft the answers using `jq` instead of `Bash` or `Boto`.
The following examples utilize `jq` with AWS cli.

This example solves what the OP was originally trying to do --

**List ELB's without instances attached:**

```
aws elb describe-load-balancers --output json |jq -r '.LoadBalancerDescriptions[] | select(.Instances==[]) | . as $l | [$l.LoadBalancerName] | @sh'
```

**Output**

> 'blah10-admin'
>   'elk-elb-nova'
>   'cj-web-elb'

This example matches the accepted answer --

**Print the ELB name and count of attached instances:**

```
aws elb describe-load-balancers --output json | jq -r '.LoadBalancerDescriptions[] | . as $l | (.Instances | length)  as $i | [$l.LoadBalancerName] + [$i] | @sh'
```

**Output**

> 'blah10-admin' 0
>   'elk-lb-cim-0' 1
>   'demo-pod-01-es' 1
>   'elk-elb-nova' 0

Answer (score 0):

This is a boto3 option how to generate csv report of unused LoadBalancers and target groups #AWS:

There are two boto clients "elb" for classic loadbalancers and "elbv2" for Application and Network.  We must use both of them in order to list our existing loadbalancers. The code below is separated for classic and others. For application and network ones, the code also listing the attached unused target groups along with the loadbalancers. As last step we have a .csv generated report.

The script below describing the loadbalancers located on the regions defined in "regions" list, update the variable for your usecase.

```html
import boto3
import csv


##################################################
# Logic for any LoadBalancer types except classic
##################################################
def describe_load_balancers(every_region):
    elbv2 = boto3.client('elbv2', region_name=every_region)
    response = elbv2.describe_load_balancers()

    return response['LoadBalancers']


def describe_target_groups(load_balancer_arn, every_region):
    elbv2 = boto3.client('elbv2', region_name=every_region)
    response = elbv2.describe_target_groups(LoadBalancerArn=load_balancer_arn)  # load_balancer_arn

    return response['TargetGroups']


def describe_target_health(target_group_arn, every_region):
    elbv2 = boto3.client('elbv2', region_name=every_region)
    target_group_response = elbv2.describe_target_health(
        TargetGroupArn=target_group_arn,
    )
    return target_group_response


regions = ['us-east-1', 'eu-central-1', 'ap-southeast-1', 'ap-southeast-2']
load_balancers_for_decom = []
target_groups_for_decom = {}
for every_region in regions:
    load_balancers = describe_load_balancers(every_region)

    for lb in load_balancers:
        lb_arn = lb['LoadBalancerArn']
        print(lb)
        target_groups = describe_target_groups(lb_arn, every_region)
        print(target_groups)
        is_active_targets = False
        for target_group_details in target_groups:
            target_group_arn = target_group_details['TargetGroupArn']
            target_health_details = describe_target_health(target_group_arn, every_region)
            if not target_health_details['TargetHealthDescriptions']:
                target_group_name = target_group_details.get('TargetGroupName', 'None')
                target_groups_for_decom.append(target_group_name)
            else:
                is_active_targets = True  # DO NOT append load balancer for decom.
            print(target_group_details['TargetGroupName'])
            print(target_health_details)
        if is_active_targets is False:  # Append the LoadBalancer for decom.
            load_balancers_for_decom.append({
                'LoadBalancerArn': lb_arn,
                'LoadBalancerName': lb['LoadBalancerName'],
                'LoadBalancerDns': lb['DNSName'],
                'LoadBalancerType': lb['Type'],
                'Region': every_region,
                'CreatedDate': lb['CreatedTime'],
                'AssociatedTargetGroups': target_groups_for_decom
            })
        target_groups_for_decom = []
print(load_balancers_for_decom)


####################################
# Logic for classic load balancers
####################################

def describe_classic_lb(every_region):
    elb = boto3.client('elb', region_name=every_region)
    response = elb.describe_load_balancers()
    return response['LoadBalancerDescriptions']


for every_region in regions:
    classic_lb = describe_classic_lb(every_region)
    for lb in classic_lb:
        if not lb['Instances']:
            print(lb['LoadBalancerName'])
            print(lb['Instances'])
            load_balancers_for_decom.append({
                'LoadBalancerArn': 'Classic load balancer does not have ARN',
                'LoadBalancerName': lb['LoadBalancerName'],
                'LoadBalancerDns': lb['DNSName'],
                'LoadBalancerType': 'Classic',
                'Region': every_region,
                'CreatedDate': lb['CreatedTime'],
                'AssociatedTargetGroups': 'N/A'
            })

###########################
# Write to .csv
###########################
report_path = 'unused_loadbalancers.csv'
field_names = load_balancers_for_decom[0].keys()
with open(report_path, 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=field_names)
    # Write header
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    # Write data
    csv_writer.writerows(load_balancers_for_decom)
```